# Doxygen not adding documentation for a function

Tags: c++, doxygen

Doxygen is not adding the documentation of any of my member functions in this class:

```
#ifndef SET_H_
#define SET_H_

/** @file */

/**
 * A mathematical set
 */
class Set
{
    virtual ~Set();

    /**
     * The countability of this set
     * @returns Whether this set is a countable one or not.
     */
    virtual bool isCountable();

    ...
}

#endif /* SET_H_ */
```

It produces the class documentation just fine, but not the function documentation even if I set `EXTRACT_ALL` to YES. Do you know why this is the case?

Answer (score 5):

The function is private unless declared otherwise as `public` or `protected`.

By default, doxygen excludes private functions, even when setting `EXTRACT_ALL` is true. You can include them by adding to the Doxyfile `EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES`.

Quoting from [Doxygen's FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#fac_al):

> Is your class / file / namespace documented? If not, it will not be
>   extracted from the sources unless EXTRACT_ALL is set to YES in the
>   config file.
>
> Are the members private? If so, you must set
>   EXTRACT_PRIVATE to YES to make them appear in the documentation.